# HttpClient error with PostAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

When making PostAsync call using HttpClient to a 3rd party API. I am seeing this error exactly when I do client.PostAsync. Any idea what could have been causing this?

Code:

```
public class JobController : AsyncController
{
    public ActionResult ViewPage()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Pages/Submit.cshtml");
    }

    private const string ServiceUrl = "https://api.3points.io/v1/applications/";

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Submit()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc123"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);

        foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
            formData.Add(new StringContent(Request.Form[key]), String.Format("\"{0}\"", key));

        foreach (string key in Request.Files.AllKeys)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[key];
            if (file == null || file.ContentLength <= 0) continue;

            HttpContent fileStream = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);
            formData.Add(fileStream, key, file.FileName);
        }

        var response = await client.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, formData);

        var success = "True";
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) success = "False";

        return new JsonResult { Data = success };
    }
}
```

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled 
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=System.Web
StackTrace:
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__1(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: `PostAsync()` is a async method, you need to consider to do await (need to add async hint to the method), or do task.Wait(), then get the response.

Comment: The same issue has been raised before without any luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713535/system-threading-tasks-task1system-web-mvc-actionresult-displayed-instead-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change

```
var response = client.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, formData).Result
```

to

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, formData);
```

And then monitor for errors after that.

Comment: This is correct. Without the await keyword the rest of the code after the PostAsync will continue to execute and return the JsonResult. If the PostAsync returns an error it may not get caught in the catch.

Comment: When I add await, it forces me to make my action method to async and to return type to Task<ActionResult>. With all those changes in place I see null exception when executing await client.PostAsync call.

Comment: The same exception, or a different one?

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried this with Fiddler running to see if the data is leaving your system and hitting the endpoint? That way you can verify the POST data has been assembled as expected.

Comment: No it is not hitting external endpoint. I do not see a request going out.

Comment: Try simplifying the post data (ideally passing nothing) - if the problem is the post data you should see the request hit the end point and get back a 400 or 404.

Comment: U saved my day its the await keyword which I didn't have

Answer (score 5):

Add these two lines to your web.config file:

```
// First tag might exist already
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

Im quoting [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx):

> Enables the new await-friendly asynchronous pipeline that was
>   introduced in 4.5. Many of our synchronization primitives in earlier
>   versions of ASP.NET had bad behaviors, such as taking locks on public
>   objects or violating API contracts. In fact, ASP.NET 4's
>   implementation of SynchronizationContext.Post is a blocking
>   synchronous call! The new asynchronous pipeline strives to be more
>   efficient while also following the expected contracts for its APIs.
>   The new pipeline also performs a small amount of error checking on
>   behalf of the developer, such as detecting unanticipated calls to
>   async void methods.
>
> Certain features like WebSockets require that this switch be set.
>   Importantly, the behavior of async / await is undefined in ASP.NET
>   unless this switch has been set. (Remember: setting  is also sufficient.)

Comment: I tried this but same issue. Does the view need to aware that its been thrown by an async controller?

Comment: I think the problem might be that the synchronization context is passed as null to the continuation callback: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745956/getting-null-reference-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-4-rc

Comment: Finally this answer solved my problem after striking head whole the day

Comment: @Lali Glad it helped :)