# Cause of Error CS0161: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I've made a basic extension method to add retry functionality to my `HttpClient.PostAsync`:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostWithRetryAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri, HttpContent content, int maxAttempts, Action<int> logRetry)
{
    if (maxAttempts < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxAttempts), "Max number of attempts cannot be less than 1.");

    var attempt = 1;
    while (attempt <= maxAttempts)
    {
        if (attempt > 1)
            logRetry(attempt);

        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            ++attempt;
            if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> Error  CS0161  'HttpClientExtensions.PostWithRetryAsync(HttpClient, Uri, HttpContent, int, Action)': not all code paths return a value.

If I add `throw new InvalidOperationException()` at the end (or `return null` for that matter), the error goes away as expected. What I'd really like to know is: is there any code path that actually exits this method without either a value being returned or an exception being thrown? I can't see it. Do I know more than the compiler in this case, or is it the other way around?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993131/httpclient-error-with-postasync-method

Comment: I would suspect that it's unable to analyse/prove the fact that *either* the `catch` block throws *or* the `while` block will not terminate.

Comment: Simply change `while (attempt <= maxAttempts)` to `while(true)`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The simple reason is that the compiler has to be able to *statically verify* that all execution flow paths end up with a return statement (or an exception).

Let's look at your code, it contains:

- Some variables controlling a `while` loop
- A `while` loop, with the `return` statement embedded
- No `return` statement *after* the loop

So basically the compiler has to verify these things:

1. That the `while` loop is actually executed
2. That the `return` statement is *always* executed
3. *Or* that some exception is always thrown instead.

The compiler is simply not able to verify this.

Let's try a very simple example:

```
public int Test()
{
    int a = 1;
    while (a > 0)
        return 10;
}
```

This trivial example will generate the exact same error:

> CS0161 'Test()': not all code paths return a value

So the compiler is not able to deduce that because of these facts:

- `a` is a local variable (meaning that only local code can impact it)
- `a` has an initial value of `1`, and is never changed
- If the `a` variable is greater than zero (which it is), the `return` statement is reached

then the code will always return the value 10.

Now look at this example:

```
public int Test()
{
    const int a = 1;
    while (a > 0)
        return 10;
}
```

Only difference is that I made `a` a `const`. Now it compiles, but this is because the optimizer  is now able to remove the whole loop, the final IL is just this:

```
Test:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0002:  ret
```

The whole `while` loop and local variable is gone, all is left is just this:

```
return 10;
```

So clearly the compiler does not look at variable values when it statically analyzes these things. The cost of implementing this feature and getting it right probably outweighs the effect or the downside of not doing it. Remember that ["Every feature starts out in the hole by 100 points, which means that it has to have a significant net positive effect on the overall package for it to make it into the language."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).

So yes, this is definitely a case where you know more about the code than the compiler.

---

Just for completeness, let's look at all the ways your code can flow:

1. It can exit early with an exception if `maxAttempts` is less than 1
2. It *will* enter the `while`-loop since `attempt` is 1 and `maxAttempts` is at least 1.
3. If the code inside the `try` statement throws a `HttpRequestException` then `attempt` is incremented and if still less than or equal to `maxAttempts` the `while`-loop will do another iteration. If it is now bigger than `maxAttempts` the exception will bubble up.
4. If some other exception is thrown, it won't get handled, and will bubble out of the method
5. If no exception is thrown, the response is returned.

So basically, this code can be said to always end up either throwing an exception or return, but the compiler is not able to statically verify this.

---

Since you have embedded the escape hatch (`attempt > maxAttempts`) in two places, both as a criteria for the `while`-loop, and additionally inside the `catch` block I would simplify the code by just removing it from the `while`-loop:

```
while (true)
{
    ...
        if (attempt > maxAttempts)
            throw;
    ...
}
```

Since you're guaranteed to run the `while`-loop at least once, and that it will actually be the `catch` block that exits it, just formalize that and the compiler will again be happy.

Now the flow control looks like this:

- The `while` loop will *always* execute (or we have already thrown an exception)
- The `while` loop will *never* terminate (no `break` inside, so no need for any code after the loop)
- The only possible way to exit the loop is either an explicit `return` or an exception, neither of which the compiler has to verify any more because the focus of this particular error message is to flag that there is potentially a way to escape the method without an explicit `return`. Since there is no way to escape the method accidentally any more the rest of the checks can simply be skipped.

  Even this method will compile:

  ```
  public int Test()
  {
      while (true)
      {
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Added a final note on how to rewrite your code to both simplify it without adding a hack and getting rid of the compiler error.

Comment: As an aside, it isn't that it would be too hard to prove in this case, but that iff the compiler proved it, it would violate the language-spec, The latter doesn't allow and require more than the most basic cases to avoid getting too convoluted, bloated, and unwieldy.

Answer (score 5):

If it throws HttpRequestException and the catch block executes, it might skip *throw* statement depending on the condition (attempt > maxAttempts) so that path wouldn't be returning anything.

Comment: The while loop will continue, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, but that also has a condition. I don't think the compiler actually checks the numeric values of variables to decide all execution paths and in this case maxAttempts is sent in from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

As Error states that `not all code paths return a value` you are not returning value for each code path

> You must throw a exception or return value

```
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        ++attempt;
        if (attempt > maxAttempts)
            throw;
        else
            return null;//you must return something for this code path
    }
```

you could modify your code so that all code path returns value. code should be something like this

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostWithRetryAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri, HttpContent content, int maxAttempts, Action<int> logRetry)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    if (maxAttempts < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxAttempts), "Max number of attempts cannot be less than 1.");

    var attempt = 1;
    while (attempt <= maxAttempts)
    {
        if (attempt > 1)
            logRetry(attempt);

        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            ++attempt;
            if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                throw;
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: That would not work as intended. The purpose of the retry-loop is to retry the POST requests in case a `HttpRequestException` is thrown, up to a number of retries.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostWithRetryAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri, HttpContent content, int maxAttempts, Action<int> logRetry)
{
    if (maxAttempts < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxAttempts), "Max number of attempts cannot be less than 1.");

    var attempt = 1;
    while (attempt <= maxAttempts)
    {
        if (attempt > 1)
            logRetry(attempt);

        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            ++attempt;
            if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                throw;
            else
                return something; // HERE YOU NEED TO RETURN SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

but in case you want to continue to loop, you need to return at the end:

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostWithRetryAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri, HttpContent content, int maxAttempts, Action<int> logRetry)
{
    if (maxAttempts < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxAttempts), "Max number of attempts cannot be less than 1.");

    var attempt = 1;
    while (attempt <= maxAttempts)
    {
        if (attempt > 1)
            logRetry(attempt);

        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            ++attempt;
            if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                throw;               
        }
    }
    return something; // HERE YOU NEED TO RETURN SOMETHING
}
```