# Extension method to throw new Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I want to write an extension method to throw new exceptions more naturally (Generally curious as to how the keyword 'throw' actually works). I want to know why the following code does not work:

```
    public static bool Foo() {
        bool bar = false;
        try {
            var zero = 0;
            // force exception
            var result = 1 / zero;
            return bar;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.ThrowNew("Failed to return Bar");
            // instead of throw new Exception("Failed to return Bar", ex);
        }
    }
```

with the ex.ThrowNew method being the following Extension method:

```
    public static void ThrowNew(this Exception ex, string message) {
        throw new Exception(message, ex);
    }
```

Obviously the Foo() method works properly when the throwing of the exception is in the catch, and not the extension method as it stops execution of the method when its thrown.

**Edit:**
The application wont compile as the the method does not all the code paths return a valid result (as the exception will be thrown in the Extension method, not the original method)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is happening? What error does it throw? As far as I can tell, this should work (And throw 'Failed to return Bar')

Comment: When you say that is doesn't work what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I have made an edit to include the compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607453/4875631) is what you're looking for. The jist is, the compiler needs to verify statically that you're returning something from every code path. Because you're using this extension method, it's not able to deduce the fact, and you're getting the error:

> CS0161 'Foo()': not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 1):

Throwing `Exception` class is a *bad practice* as well as catching `Exception` without re-throwing via `throw;` (please, notice the syntax):

```
// Whatever happened (e.g. CPU starts emittinig green smoke) 
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // throw Exception instance which means nothing more than "Something went wrong"
   ex.ThrowNew("Failed to return Bar");
}
```

First, let us amend the initial code:

```
try {
  ...
}
// We do know the cause, that's why we have a right to catch and re-throw 
catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
  // Be specific, do not throw Exception! Since MyBarException can be caought in "catch"
  throw new MyBarException("Failed to return Bar because...", e);
}
```

I doubt if you want any extension method here, however, if you insist you should put something like

```
// Doesn't compile; to show the idea only
public static void ThrowNew<T>(this Exception ex, string message) 
  where T: Exception {

  if (null == ex)
    return; // or throw ArgumentNullException("ex");

  throw new T(message, ex); // <- this line fails to compile
}
```

The code above has a problem with `new T` (.Net can't be sure that arbitrary `T` has the constructor 
required), so you have to add *Reflection* for that

```
public static void ThrowNew<T>(this Exception ex, string message) 
  where T: Exception {

  if (null == ex)
    return; // or throw ArgumentNullException("ex");

  throw (Exception) (typeof(T)
    .GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(String), typeof(Exception)})
    .Invoke(message, ex));
}
```

And so you can put

```
    catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
      e.ThrowNew<MyBarException>("Failed to return Bar because...");

      // Ugly little thing: 
      // "if (null == ex)" in the extension method doesn't throw any exception
      return false;
    }
```

which is, IMHO, *less readable* and thus should not be used

Comment: Using the above implementation I still sit with the initial issue with 'Not all code paths return a value' The thing is I was just wondering why the compiler does not pick up the thrown exception in the extension method. The answer FrankerZ referenced explains why this is happening